# i have lost office 10 and outlook on my pc

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have lost my office 10 on my PC! I can see all my folders but they are empty. Can I get it back by installing 365?
If my question has all these elements but is still blocked for not meeting quality standards, i feel that this is in error.

What types of questions can I asking?

---

I apologize for the lack of information. I'm not a super user, so I'm asking for your help. I can see excel and word in file management, but I can't open them. the same with outlook, there are pst files that can only be opened from outlook, but outlook 10 is gone. All my office 2010 is gone. I do not have the installation CD or key as it was installed by my company in 2008. Today the company no longer exists. I don't know why 2010 shut down, whether it was me who made a mistake or it was microsoft when they announced that they no longer support 2010. Translated via Google.

Comment: "Can I get it back by installing 365?" - No; Did you really have Microsoft Office XP installed in 2024?  Microsoft Office XP of course is Office 10, or do you mean Office 2010, since you used that tag?  [Edit] your question to clarify it.  Office 365 of course cannot be used in leu of Office 2010.

Comment: You can see folders of what? Your question is scattered, lacks detail and context, and doesn't give enough clear information for us to understand what may be happening. Please start at the beginning, tell us what was working, what happened, what is now NOT working, using clear and precise words and phrases as you do.

Comment: Do you or your friends have the installation file CD?

Comment: If you hold down the Windows key on the keyboard and tap `R`, you should get a box you can type in. Type `winword` and press enter. Does Word start?

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 is something like version 16. So installing it will not recover Office 10.

Also Office 365 need different kind of license.

The best you can do is to install Office from original media you initially install it.

Comment: It's office 2010. I can't explain why I lost it. I can see my files in the overview but cannot open them. I cannot access outlook 10 where I have many saved folders. What do I do ?

Comment: @hlin, reinstall from the media you install it first time.

Comment: Unfortunately, my English is not good enough for this group. I got office 10 when it came out. I have lost the office suite on my PC and am unable to open folders, files and emails. I am asking for help on which program I need to buy to gain access again

Answer (score -1):

@hlin...You need to buy a copy of Office 2010...You could install LibreOffice, which is free. This will open Word docs. Not sure about your other files and emails though.

Comment: Author wants to use Office not LibreOffice.